# Benefits of using pointer in this example?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm beginning with C++ , and really don't see the advantage of pointer. 
I see many people say pointer helps to save memory or good in memory management.

Like bellow examples, they return the same result, what different if i use pointer in this case?

Without pointer

```
typedef struct
{
   int   book_id;
} Books;

 void printbookinf( Books book );

int main( )
{
    Books bno1;
    Books bno2;

   bno1.book_id = 1225;
   bno2.book_id = 3214;

   printbookinf( bno1 );
   printbookinf( bno2 );

   return 0;
}
void printbookinf( Books book )
{
   printf("abc %d",book.book_id);
}
```

with pointer

```
typedef struct
{
   int   book_id;
} Books;

 void printbookinf( Books *book );

int main( )
{
    Books bno1;
    Books bno2;

   bno1.book_id = 1225;
   bno2.book_id = 3214;

   printbookinf( &bno1 );
   printbookinf( &bno2 );

   return 0;
}
void printbookinf( Books *book )
{
   printf("abc %d",book->book_id);
}
```

or this

```
typedef struct
    {
       int   book_id;
    } Books;

 void printbookinf( Books *book );

int main( )
{
    Books *bno1;
    Books *bno2;

   bno1->book_id = 1225;
   bno2->book_id = 3214;

   printbookinf( bno1 );
   printbookinf( bno2 );

   return 0;
}
void printbookinf( Books *book )
{
   printf("abc %d",book->book_id);
}
```

Comment: There are no benefits in this case, and example #3 is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see many people say pointer helps to save memory or good in memory management.

That's not what pointers are for in general. In your example the pointers would have helped you save memory and transfer of data, had the `struct` been larger than a pointer.

The first example copies the `struct` when passing parameter. This means two things:

- The whole structure, even a large one, would be copied, and the copy would be passed to the function
- Any modifications inside the function would be invisible to the caller.

The second example passes a pointer, so

- Only the pointer gets copied, and
- Changes, if any, are performed on the original parameter passed to the function.

Your third example has undefined behavior, because pointers that you pass are unassigned.

**Note:** Your question does not ask about references, but there is a construct that is closely related to pointers that lets you save space on argument copying, and it lets the function make modifications to the original value. All that happens while keeping the dot `.` syntax for accessing members, as if it were a `struct`, not a pointer.

Comment: So, as my understanding, passing struct object `bno1` , `bno2` in the first will cost more memory than the second one?

Comment: @TomSawyer Not in your example, because the size of `bno1` and `bno2` is smaller or is equal to the size of a pointer. For larger structs - say, with three or more fields, the first example would cost more memory in the automatic storage.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use C++, it will be better to use standard libraries. These libraries are efficient, hide the complexity (and troubles) of pointers and sometimes easier to debug the codes. However in some case, it has shown using `std::vector` array and pointer array produce the same Assembly code.

Comment: the question do not mention `array` at all

Comment: It is just an example. In general , we mainly use pointers for arrays.